# Bot name as prefix

Tags: discord.js

I want to be able to make the prefix the name of the bot so I can do like

```
 if(cmd === `${prefix}Hey`) {
            const m = await message.channel.send(`Hello`);
      }
```

Where you could use the bot name as prefix "(Bot name) hey" and it would answer hello back since when I try you can only do it without the space like
"(bot name)hey" and it would answer hello back.
I don't know if that made sense.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

This may helping you. [Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=username)

```
if (cmd.startsWith(message.client.user.username)) {
    const command = cmd.replace(message.client.user.username, "").toLowerCase();
    if (command === "hey") {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like this in your main file :

```js
const client = new Client(); // Just to represent the bot
client.on('message', (message) => {
  const mentionRegex = new RegExp(`^<@!?${client.user.id}>`);
  if (mentionRegex.test(message.content) ||
      message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {

    let cmd; 
    const words = message.content.split(' ');
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix) {
      cmd = words.shift().slice(prefix.length)
    } else {
      cmd = words.splice(0, 1, '').shift();
    }

    switch (cmd) {
      case 'hey':
        message.channel.send('Hello!');
        break;
    }
  }
});
```